# Can Quantity interpretation be accepted using the keyboard?

Tags: units, keyboard

Entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> on selected text results in the display of an interpreted `Quantity`, with the option to accept it, or choose other interpretations.  The only way I know of to accept the interpretation is using the pointer to click the check-mark.  Is there a way of accepting the interpretation using the keyboard?

Edit to add:  I want to do this within a Text Cell.  Also, I am using version 
"10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)".

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't actually need to accept it to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend accepting input using in-place evaluation. This is done with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> in MacOS. On Windows it is probably done using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>. In order to use in-place evaluation you first need to select the input, which you can do using <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>, if the cursor is placed to the right of the input.

Example:

[image: Example of in-place evaluation.]

As a sidenote, I also recommend this approach for prettifying input with entities:

[image: A second example of in-place evaluation.]

Normally the entity would stay formatted as code (`Entity["Country", "Sweden"]`), but I can represent it with the more visually pleasing entity representation that we are used to seeing in output by using in-place evaluation.

Comment: In Windows, in-place evaluation is done with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Answer (score 1):

For programmatic, non-interactive use, where you just want to take the first result, I recommend [`Interpreter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html) over <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd>,

```
Interpreter["Quantity"] /@ {"16 miles per hour", "22 gallons", 
  "twelve parsecs", "4 widgets"}
```

[image]